# What are the low-budget options for developing mobile ios applications using Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am a student trying to develop an app for a friend using Xamarin. In order to test an IOS app, apple requires an actual Mac to be used to test the application, which can be accessed remotely.

There are a few options I have considered. One would be to try to temporarily use my brother's Mac, but he lives on the other side of the country. I am assuming the Mac Agent used does not have to be on the same local network as the PC I am using, but that option would not always be accessible to me.

Another option would be to find a cheap used Mac to serve primarily as the Mac Agent. I currently have very little income and so if I did this option, I wouldn't be able to spend very much, and I am unsure what models would be capable of handling the workload and would also be able to run the newest version of XCode which I believe is a requirement.

So my question(s):
- Has anyone else had experience with these issues?
- Would either of my ideas work / how old of a Mac would be a viable option?
- Are there any alternatives that would work for testing a simple app?

Comment: You can look at renting a cloud mac server such as this one for USD$20/month. http://www.macincloud.com/pricing/compare They support Xamarin as detailed here .. https://support.macincloud.com/support/solutions/articles/8000032728-xamarin-updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course I had.

First of all, I have tried to set up the Mac Agent with an Mac in an external Network. I wasn't able to set the Xamarin Agent stable up. Sometimes I could connect, other times not and the connection suddenly stopped working.

So this was not an option for me.

Next, I searched around for a hosted mac. But this was to expensive for me. Also no option. And there is one thing which is missing for me when the mac isn't in your location: The deploy process isn't as easy as just plug your phone in the Mac and click deploy.

Last, I bought only the Software OSX and got it installed in an VM with some hacks. That's the point where i'm now. So I develop on Windows (Visual Studio and Xamarin) and set up a Xamarin Agent in the VM. The connection worked fine. I plugged my phone into the host computer and linked it to the Mac. I was now even able to deploy the app to my iPhone with just one click.

To the question of the age of your mac:
You can install the newest version of xCode on a very old Mac. You only need to have OS X El Capitan.
You can read which devices you can use here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan

Comment: That is very helpful. I considered trying the VM route. I have set up a few VM's before, but the OSX VM's seemed to be very difficult to get working properly. Is there a specific VM type that you found to work better than others? As far as I know the main ones are VMWare and VirtualBox.

Comment: I am using VMWare. I had problems in VirtualBox with the screen resolution. So I am able to code on the mac (eg in xCode or Xamarin Studio directly). But if you don't want  to have the OS X Screen in fullscreen and high resolution, VirtualBox should fit your needs too.